# INTERBASE - INDEX ISSUE

Tags: interbase

Good day,
I run many databases under interbase XE7 and 2017 now.
Lately, I got a strange behavior on one of the db:
A table with a primary key was found hosting many rows with similar values, like image below.
We can see that SCRIPTTYPE is a primary key column and it contains many times MATRIX, no space or strange characters ( I checked).
I was able to backup / restore without issues.
I am puzzled by this and I am wondering if anybody did encountered something similar?
And how it was done?
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoK5m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query to be sure:

select SCRIPTTYPE, count(*)
from yourtable
group by SCRIPTTYPE
order by 2 desc

If you get a count>1, then I'd argue it's simple a bug and you should contact support. For them to assist you they'll almost certainly need your database, so you should be prepared to provide that. Based on your description, you should be able to drop all tables except the one, and drop all fields except your key, then backup and restore to get the simplest test case.

Comment: Thanks Quinn, I will see with support.